# 404 page is getting mixed up with maintenance page.

Tags: bug, status-deferred

This page should probably be a 404, but instead it says the site is offline for maintenance.

http://api.math.stackexchange.com/posts/

I am aware that that is not supposed to be a valid URL, but I thought I would just let you know that the wrong message is being displayed.

Comment: How did you come across this bug?

Comment: @mixed: It was sort of an accident.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of how the load balancer handles api requests (a separate API backend in HAProxy)...we'll just say that part of the API is offline at the moment?

It's not technically correct, no, but it's not a high priority issue either.

Comment: Totally understand. I only mentioned it because it looked wrong - not because it was really important.